# How to compute the convex conjugate for $x\mapsto 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis

I have to compute the convex conjugate (Fenchel) and the subgradients for the following two functions:

$\boxed{f_1:[-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}:x\mapsto 0}$ and

$\boxed{f_2:\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2:||x||_2\leq 1\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}:x\mapsto 0}$

I have done this for different functions so far which seems much more complicated than this. So I'm not sure if understand this problem right. The functions are differentiable in every $x$, so the subgradients are equal to the gradients. For both function this is 1. Is this right? What about the convex conjugate? I have no idea how to start this here. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What do you know about the definition of convex conjugate?  For example, $$\phi^{**}(x) = \sup\limits_{f \in E'} \{\langle f,x \rangle - \phi^*(f)\},$$ where $\phi^*(f)$ is the convex conjugate of $\phi$.

Comment: Any linear form on $[-1,1]$ takes the form $f(x)=tx$ for some $t\in\Bbb R$. By abuse of notation, $$f_1^*(t)=\sup\limits_{x\in[-1,1]}\{f(x)-f_1(x)\}=|t|.$$  For the 2nd part, we consider a linear form $f(x,y)=ax+by$ on $\Bbb R^2$ and use Cauchy-Schwarz to show that $$f_2^*(a,b)=\sup\limits_{\lVert x\rVert_2\le1}\{ax_1+bx_2-f_2(x)\}=\lVert(a,b)\rVert_2.$$